# How do I stream an uploaded video on Azure Media Services

Tags: azure, video, azure-media-services

I uploaded a video to Azure Media Services, and clicked the "publish" button.  That gave me a publish URL.

I then used the Azure Media Player (http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/samples.html) to embed my video content on a page.

The problem I'm having is that the video is choppy to start.  Perhaps it's the encoding of the video, but I want to make sure, if I want to stream a video, using the media player or anything else, do I just use the "Publish URL"?  OR is there a different way of requesting video content to "smooth stream"?

Comment: Use the Azure Media Explorer tool to make your life easier as well. http://aka.ms/amse

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You use the publish URL for VOD and you have a few url parameters to change the type of streaming if needed. Default is smooth streaming.

**Smooth Streaming**

{streaming endpoint name-media services account name}.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/{locator ID}/{filename}.ism/Manifest

**HLS Streaming**

{streaming endpoint name-media services account name}.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/{locator ID}/{filename}.ism/Manifest(format=m3u8-aapl)

**MPEG Dash Streaming**

{streaming endpoint name-media services account name}.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/{locator ID}/{filename}.ism/Manifest(format=mpd-time-csf)

See what works best for you

You can also test on this page and try the advanced settings

http://amsplayer.azurewebsites.net/azuremediaplayer.html

Comment: Thanks @BrunoFaria, my Publish URL doesn't look like that format at all though (at least i dont think it does..) - This is the publish URL from one of my videos - https://gwcstorage1.blob.core.windows.net/asset-010f435d-1500-80c3-2659-f1e4d3be272c/WhyVSC-IPAD.mp4?sv=2012-02-12&sr=c&si=8d79b629-46c3-4012-bfbb-05bbee7d9d17&sig=t4g5LK18MYYB1etkvwVjRWzdwhUvK3Oly0mjcEiq0tc%3D&st=2015-03-26T13%3A44%3A56Z&se=2017-03-25T13%3A44%3A56Z

Comment: ah got it. It is only pointing to the asset in your blob storage account not the asset stored in media services. Probably the encoding has failed or you never started it. Try to upload and encode it again (using media services not locally in your machine) and see if you get the proper url. Anytime you see "blob.core.windows.net" instead of "streaming.mediaservices.windows.net" something went wrong or you missed one of the steps. Basically upload the video, select it, hit proccess and choose desired encoding, wait for the job to finish and publish the output file (not the source).

Comment: I've never encoded any of these!  Thanks so much Bruno, Apprently whatever Ive been doing has been "wrong", thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Media Services test page has changed since the last post. The new URL is:

https://ampdemo.azureedge.net/azuremediaplayer.html